# In-memory cache plus mutex in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, server, scalability, wsgi

I'm working on a very interesting project where we want to keep our game state in memory. When the server starts up, it loads the game state from the database, and that's the only time it ever reads from the database. Whenever the server changes its in-memory game state, it will issue a corresponding write to the database.

Every game is written to by only one server, and if a client sends an update to the wrong server, it is told the correct server's url, and the client can try again.

So, I'm looking for a way to have this game state persist in memory on App Engine, but I'm having a hard time. Everywhere I see says that one should not have state in memory like this, but it's a requirement for our system.

How do I have state in an App Engine server?

PS. Please don't tell me to change my design so that I don't have state in my server, that is a hard requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Every instance has its own instance memory, which you can specify in settings.

The problems you are going to face:

1. Routing requests to the "correct" instances.
2. Instances may be restarted at any time.

You can keep your game states in Memcache, which acts as "memory" shared by all of your instances. This way your instances may become "stateless" - each instance finds the correct "game" in Memcache and updates it (and then the Datastore).

Comment: Thanks! So if I'm understanding this correctly, there's instance memory, and there's also memcache. I'll explore switching to a model more compatible with memcache sometime in the future, but for now, I'll try to do the instance memory approach. Where in the settings can I find it? I see the memcache settings and the cloud storage bucket settings, but not instance memory...

Comment: You define the "instance class" in your deployment description, e.g. appengine-web.xml or app.yaml (depending on your runtime). See: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes